# SPRESENSE IDEにて、SDKコンフィグが開けません

Tags: spresense

Spresense:SDKコンフィグを選択すると下記のエラーが出て、コンフィグが開けません。

**エラー内容**

```
"コンフィグファイルの解析中にエラーが発生しました"
```

どのように対応すればよいでしょうか。

**■ 環境**

- PC：Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
- SDK：v2.0.1
- IDE：v1.2.0

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

一度ターミナルを開いてmake distcleanを実行すれば解決すると思います。

こちらが参考になると思います。
「SPRESENSE SDK v2.0.1でSDKコンフィグに失敗する場合の対処方法」
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mEHxqGmktSc

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
解決致しました。